# Preventing unauthorised installation of software in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, security, malware

Last night I complained to my wife that in Windows 8 the new Metro interface is so important that Microsoft has valued it over a usable clock. So I commented that I needed to find a widget or something to fix that. She kindly tried to install something she thought was from Microsoft. It was a "clock" program from some site called thoosje that installed multiple programs and changed my home screen on IE and Firefox. I uninstalled all of it I could find. IE let me reset the home screen. Firefox needed to be reinstalled. Malwarebytes couldn't find anything nor did Windows Defender. I don't see anything I couldn't identify as native in the process list under Task Manager either.

Questions:

Am I paranoid or was my reflex to call that malware appropriate?
Is it all gone or is there a setting somewhere still likely to cause problems?
Short of trying to forbid my wife from installing anything is there a way to stop her from installing obnoxious crap on my new build?

Comment: We can't judge whether it was truly malware or not; SU isn't a malware testing service. What you can do however is use standard user accounts instead of admin accounts so that the possibility of widespread system damage is reduced.

Comment: Sorry, I won't ask for the benefit of people's expertise on this site that I mistakenly took for a place where people share expertise. You have my deepest apologies. I will endeavor to never ask for advice or the benefit of other people's experience here again. What can I do here then by the way?

Comment: You can cut the snark and focus on the actual question, which is how to prevent installation of such iffy programs in future without your express consent. Your original question title was non-constructive and off-topic for this site. You can't expect people here to test an app no-one's heard of and tell you whether it was malware or whether it can be trusted etc. That's not what this site is meant for. If you want the app to be analysed further, there are other sites/fora that are more suited to this. Edit: I have rolled back your title edit. If you want to debate this head over to meta.su

Comment: I was at no point asking anyone to test or decompile the software. I was asking if anyone knew about it. I'm sorry this question was so deeply offensive to you. But I also suggest that you have run off with an mistaken impression of my question and are continuing to refuse to listen to what I'm saying. You are complaining and attacking me for doing something I did not do. Since this is obviously not constructive and you have nothing of use to share, I will move on.

Comment: not really a solution but actually limiting the permissions of the only one account (because there is a built-in administrator account in windows) could solve your issue of widespreading any malware onto the system.

Comment: You can choose to word it in any way, but asking whether anyone knows if ABC site's XYZ software is malware or not is not what this site is meant for. Questions like that are likely to be closed as too localized or off-topic etc. Final word - the *question* wasn't offensive and I edited the title to bring it in line with what's allowed, but you were the one who seemed to take great offence at this. I advise you to read the FAQ carefully before posting next time; we welcome all on-topic queries. Also, instead of deleting your question in a huff you should post on meta or flag for mod attention.

Comment: No, I couldn't. Until someone voted me up I didn't have access to meta. Deleting it myself seemed sensible and conciliatory, but how you choose to take it is your decision. It's a new week, time to move on.

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict her by creating/adjusting her account type in Users under control panel. Change from an administrator to Standard User. I am not responsible for any damage you may receive once she finds out.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds dangerous. She is though. She just knows my passwords.